# Asp.Net Core 2.0 Azure Ad authentication in default Razor Pages app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

Web app created with VS 2017 default template has the following Startup.ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
    .AddCookie();

    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    })
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Account");
    });
}
```

So, Authorize filter is applied globally, even for Index home page (the exceptions are /Account/AccessDenied and /Account/SignedOut pages, which are applied [AllowAnonymous] in the above code). That means, when the app starts it immediately goes to Microsoft login page, which is fine for my case.

AccountController have the following code:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SignIn()
    {
        var redirectUrl = Url.Page("/Index");
        return Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl },
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        );
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SignOut()
    {
        var callbackUrl = Url.Page("/Account/SignedOut", pageHandler: null, values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
        return SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        );
    }
}
```

Here, AccountController.Signin will have [Authorize] applied implicitly, because of the Authorize filter, applied globally. Apparently, the code won't run, unless user first signs out and explicitly requests `/account/signin` url. But even in that case, the first thing to happen is implicit [Authorize] filter, and the code runs only after the user successfully signs in. So, the question is, what is the point of returning ChallengeResult, because the user should have already been authenticated at that point? Maybe, just redirect to Index page like below?

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SignIn()
{
    return RedirectToPage("/Index");
}
```

Or, like below, why not apply [AllowAnonymous] to AccountController.SignIn, so that it will run immediately, when user requests `/account/signin` url?

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult SignIn()
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Page("/Index");
    return Challenge(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl },
        OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
    );
}
```

One more question. I want to execute some code, right after user signs in. Where to put that code, if AccountController.SignIn will not run, unless explicitly requested? Default template created another class, called AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions. Should I hook up to OpenId events in that class and put my code in those event handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One situation where the user would see the login link would be after they signed out.
In a sense, redirecting to the Index page has the same effect as the challenge in your case.
Your `AccountController` should have `[AllowAnonymous]` since it does not really make sense otherwise.

To do something after login, there are various events you can hook into on the OpenId Connect handler. The `OnTicketReceived` event might work for you.
You can see all of the events available on the [OpenIdConnectEvents](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/Events/OpenIdConnectEvents.cs) and its base class [RemoteAuthenticationEvents](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/Events/RemoteAuthenticationEvents.cs).